# value of $\tan B\tan C$ in a triangle

Tags: conic-sections

> In a triangle $ABC,$ equation of side $BC$ is $2x-y=3$ and circumcenter and orthocenter of triangle are $(2,4)$ and $(1,2)$ respectively, Then $\tan B\tan C=$

what i try

In a triangle, Let $BC$ be base side and $H(1,2)$ be orthocenter of triangle and $O(2,4)$ be orthocenter of triangle.

and we know that Image of orthocenter $H(1,2)$ of triangle $ABC$ with respect to side $BC$ lie on circumference of  Circumcirlce of $\triangle ABC$

for image point coordinate

using formula

$\displaystyle \frac{x-x_{1}}{a}=\frac{y-y_{1}}{b}=-\frac{(ax_{1}+by_{1}+c)}{a^2+b^2}$

above image of point $P(x_{1},y_{1})$ w. r to line $ax+by+c=0$

$$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-2}{-1}=-\frac{2(1)-2-3}{2^2+1^2}$$

Coordinate of any point Image point which lie on circumcircle is $$(x,y)=\bigg(\frac{11}{5},\frac{7}{5}\bigg)$$

so circumradius of circle is $$\sqrt{\bigg(2-\frac{11}{5}\bigg)^2+\bigg(4-\frac{7}{5}\bigg)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{170}}{5}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Your point $(11/5, 7/5)$ is not on the circumcircle: it's just the projection of $H$ on line $BC$.

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ is the intersection of altitude $AH$ with $BC$, and $H'$ the reflection of $H$ about $BC$, then:
$$
\tan B\cdot\tan C={AK\over BK}\cdot{AK\over CK}={AK^2\over AK\cdot KH'}=
{AK\over KH'}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Aretion but answer is integer

Comment: Why shouldn't that be integer? Did you compute the result?

Comment: u mean using $AK=2R\cos A$ and $KH'=4R\cos B\cos C$ where $R$ is circumradius of circle

Comment: No, I mean computing the coordinates of $A$, $K$ and $H'$. You already have $K=(11/5,7/5)$ and can thus find $H'$. Intersecting then line $AH$ with the circumcircle you can also find $A$.